# HTML &quot; not converting to "

Tags: javascript, html

I am displaying data from an HTML encoded JSON object onto an HTML page using innerHTML property.

```
var td = document.createElement("td");
td.innerHTML = data[i].name; // data[i].name = 'Audioslave 7&quot;'
```

But instead of displaying this as Audioslave 7", it shows same `Audioslave 7&quot;`

I tried to do .toString() with no avail. I also tried

```
var td = document.createElement("td");
td.innerHTML = data[i].name + ' &gt;'; // data[i].name = 'Audioslave 7&quot;'
```

In this case, gt shows up correctly as > but qout is still not showing up.

I am using HTML5 and this occurs in Chrome as well as Safari.

What should I do to make it display correctly?

Comment: Any reason you can't just use `data[i].name = 'Audioslave 7"'`?

Comment: What method are you using to display it on the page? I tried to recreate this [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2FERe/) and it worked fine in Chrome

Comment: Are you sure it's not `&amp;quot;` and you are looking at the decoded version

Comment: @Oded the object comes from server with AJAX. This is not static.

Comment: @mihsathe - this is in the AJAX response? Can you control what comes from the server?

Comment: @Explosion Pills you are absolutely right. I was HTML Encoding text twice on the server. Thank you.

Comment: @Explosion Pills please add this as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are printing out the text as html it will appear correctly.  If you want to debug, make sure you are printing it out as unencoded text.

In your case it will appear as `&amp;quot;`, which in turn is decoded by browsers into `&quot;`.  It seems that you are double-escaping at some point.